# Convert list table to matrix table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in SQL:

```
Name  | Date  | Property  | Value
------------------------------------
Name1 | Date1 | PropertyA | Value11A
Name1 | Date1 | PropertyB | Value11B
Name1 | Date2 | PropertyA | Value12A
Name1 | Date2 | PropertyB | Value12B
Name2 | Date1 | PropertyA | Value21A
Name2 | Date1 | PropertyB | Value21B
Name2 | Date2 | PropertyA | Value22A
Name2 | Date2 | PropertyB | Value22B
------------------------------------
```

And would like to have the following output:

```
Name  | Date  | PropertyAValue | PropertyBValue
-----------------------------------------------
Name1 | Date1 | Value11A       | Value11B
Name1 | Date2 | Value12A       | Value12B
Name2 | Date1 | Value21A       | Value21B
Name2 | Date2 | Value22A       | Value22B
```

I constructed something that works with a lot of select/where statements. But the query gets really heavy once you have 10 properties. Can you please assist with something more efficient.

Edit: I am on Oracle. I had a look at the pivot function as well, but it only works for aggregated values but I don't aggregate anything only reformat the table and take one value as a column.

Comment: Use `PIVOT`, ....http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: please add tag of the DB server you are working on...Oracle, MySQL ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIVOT` can be used in SQL Server to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT Name, Date, [PropertyA] AS PropertyAValue , [PropertyB] AS PropertyBValue
FROM
(SELECT * FROM your_table) p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value) 
    FOR Property IN ([PropertyA],[PropertyB])
) AS pvt
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98818/4)

This is an Oracle equivalent for above query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Name, Date1, Property, Value
        FROM   your_table)
PIVOT  (MAX(Value)  FOR (Property) IN ('PropertyA' AS PropertyA, 'PropertyB' AS PropertyB))
ORDER BY Name, Date1;
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77bb8/4)

Comment: Welcome, you can try `PIVOT` in Oracle

Comment: It only works if you aggregate values, but I need all the values individually by just restructuring the table.

Comment: As there is a unique value for a column and row combination, using `MAX` would basically result into same unique value being displayed for the row column combination. In this particular case, `PIVOT` results into restructuring of data without any real aggregation even though we have used `MAX` but that is just to comply with the syntax.